Create Matrix by Multiplying ith and jth Vector-Element in Numpy
I need to calculate a the error function V
V = Σi Σj X[i] X[j] σ[i][j]

Where σ[i][j] is a given matrix and I need a relatively fast solution. To do this I want to create another matrix Y where
Y[i][j] = X[i]*X[j]

So I that I can simply sum over Y * σ. Is there a good way to implement this with numpy functions?
So far I have tried to meshgrid(X, X) and then apply np.prod to each row, however this did yield the expected output and would have required a for-loop in python.
Edit: Minimal reproducable example:
cov = np.array(((0.1, 0.05), (0.05, 0.25)))
x = np.array((0.6, 0.4)

desired = x[0]*x[0]*cov[0][0] + x[0]*x[1]*cov[0][1] + x[1]*x[0]*cov[1][0] + x[1]*x[1] * cov[1][1]


Could you please give a small explicit [mre] with the matching expected output?

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html

np.outer and np.einsum are the way to go, but please note that creating such a (temporary?) matrice in memory is inefficient in the first place if it is big (because it is memory-bound, and DRAMs are pretty slow nowadays.

Use x @ s @ x

np.dot supports matrix multiplication.
Simply do
np.dot(x,sigma).dot(x)


IF you see his first equation OP wants to get a scalar error. He does an outer product only as a intermediate calculation. Updated to reflect that in this case both x and y are the same thing as you correctly pointed

you could also add x @ sigma @ x.

@Onyambu np.dot(a, b) is equivalent to a @ b when a matrix multiplication can be applied. Both will call BLAS routines which should take nearly all the time on sufficiently large input. The only difference, is the Numpy overhead only visible on small inputs.

Benchmark


Note that both X and Y scales are logarithmic.
The simple np.dot(x,sigma).dot(x) is faster than the np.einsum("i,j,ij->", x, x, s) solution at all problem sizes.
einsum(..., optimize=True) has a high startup cost, but enters a 3-way tie for first after N = 1000 or so.
I wrote a simple implementation in Numba. It is the fastest solution for problems up to N = 500 or so, and then it is in a 3 way tie from then on.
I also benchmarked (x @ s) @ x, and einsum() with a precomputed contraction path, but those were very similar to other results.

My solution
Numba solution code
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def numba_multiply(x, s):
    V = 0
    N = len(x)
    assert s.ndim == 2 and s.shape[0] == N and s.shape[1] == N
    # Note: this iteration order is fastest if s is a C ordered
    # array. If it is Fortran ordered, it is better to swap these
    # two for loops.
    # See https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            V += x[i] * x[j] * s[i, j]
    return V

Full benchmark code
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import perfplot


@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def numba_multiply(x, s):
    V = 0
    N = len(x)
    assert s.ndim == 2 and s.shape[0] == N and s.shape[1] == N
    # Note: this iteration order is fastest if s is a C ordered
    # array. If it is Fortran ordered, it is better to swap these
    # two for loops.
    # See https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/internals.html#multidimensional-array-indexing-order-issues
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(N):
            V += x[i] * x[j] * s[i, j]
    return V


# precompile Numba function
x_tmp = np.random.normal(size=10)
s_tmp = np.random.normal(size=(10, 10))
numba_multiply(x_tmp, s_tmp)


# precompute path
einsum_path, _ = np.einsum_path("i,j,ij", x_tmp, x_tmp, s_tmp)


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: (np.random.rand(n), np.random.rand(n, n)),
    kernels=[
        # Credit: Nick ODell
        lambda x, s: numba_multiply(x, s),
        # Credit: Tarifazo
        lambda x, s: np.dot(x, s).dot(x),
        # Credit: simon
        lambda x, s: np.einsum("i,j,ij", x, x, s),
        # Credit: Jérôme Richard
        lambda x, s: np.einsum("i,j,ij", x, x, s, optimize=True),
        # Credit: simon
        lambda x, s: (np.outer(x, x) * s).sum(),
    ],
    labels=[
        "numba",
        "dot product",
        "einsum",
        "einsum optimize",
        "outer product",
    ],
    n_range=[2**k for k in np.linspace(0, 14, 20)],
    xlabel="len(x)",
    equality_check=np.allclose,
)


Note the Numba code with fastmath less safe than other methods since fastmath assume for example there is no NaN or Inf or subnormal numbers (while other solution should not).

why would you benchmark x @ s @ s instead of x @ s @ x?
